# Inertia / Laravel PATCH redirect is also trying to update referrer

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I have a Laravel / InertiaJS app where I perform Axios requests from the Vue frontend to update certain models. In my case, I have a **Proposal** show page that also shows **Tasks** related to that Proposal.

I have a Vue subcomponent that executes an Axios call to update a specific task:

```
const moveToNextStatus = (status) => {
    console.log('run')
    // update the status of the task using axios
    axios.patch(`/data/tasks/${props.task.id}`, {
        status: status
    })
}
```

This is the route it is referring to:

```
Route::patch('/data/tasks/{task}', [\App\Http\Controllers\TaskController::class, 'update'])->name('tasks.update');
```

Then, within my Laravel **TaskController** this is what my update method looks like:

```
public function update (Request $request, Task $task)
{
    $task->update($request->all());

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

For some reason, when that Axios request to PATCH /tasks/{task} fires, it also calls the route **PATCH /proposals/{proposal}** and tries to update the proposal which fails.

Maybe this has something to do with redirecting from a subcomponent? Could someone please help me out here?

Answer (score 1):

Inertia's documentation states;

> 303 response code
> When redirecting after a PUT, PATCH, or DELETE request, you must use a 303 response code, otherwise the subsequent request will not be treated as a GET request. A 303 redirect is very similar to a 302 redirect; however, the follow-up request is explicitly changed to a GET request.
>
> If you're using one of our official server-side adapters, all redirects will automatically be converted to 303 redirects.

You can find this in the docs here: https://inertiajs.com/redirects

It also wants you to use non-standard helpers for redirects, such as;

```
    return to_route('users.index');
```

I don't agree with it, but there it is - seems like it goes against the web status code standards to use a 303 when the page hasn't redirected at all.